# Why page-scroll class doesn't behave as usual after using replaceWith()? Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Problem:**

I am replacing the content of a div with:

```
$('#cita').delay(2000).fadeTo(9000, 1)
$('#cita').delay(6500).fadeTo(2000, 0).queue(function(next) {
$(this).replaceWith('<div class="page-scroll col-sm-12"><a href="#one" class="page-scroll btn btn-primary btn-xl">Find out what confuses me</a></div>');
next();
}).delay("200").fadeIn("2000");
```

However, when I click the link in the new created element, the `page-scroll` class doesn't behave as expected (there isn't a smooth transition to the section).

For those not familiar with Bootstrap, the class page-scroll is used just for establishing a dependency in js, as I have never seen this class defined on any Bootstrap Theme or in the framework itself. If you click in an element with this class, this happens:

```
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $ele = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: ($($ele.attr('href')).offset().top - 60)
    }, 1450, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Problems with libraries or class dependencies?:**

I am nearly 100% sure that it's not a problem with jQuery or other libraries, as it works fine with other links.

In the past, I had a similar problem and I resolved it by not giving the page-scroll class to the element itself, but its parent. Here I tried the same (not only with its parent, but also with the "grandpas") but it seems not a good solution.

I have also changed `$('a.page-scroll')` for `$('.page-scroll')` to make the event 100% dependent to class, and not to class + tag. It doesn't work neither.

**Demo:**

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/28af8rjx/embedded/result/)

You have to wait for the quote to fade out. The new element "Find out what confuses me" will appear and you can test it by yourself. If you click on other links, you will see that the links with class `page-scroll` work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding your function to `a.page-scroll` but then you **remove that element** and add a new one in it's place. The new one will not have that binding anymore.

Change you function to :

```
$(document).on('click','a.page-scroll', function(event) {
    var $ele = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: ($($ele.attr('href')).offset().top - 60)
    }, 1450, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Note**  that `document` should really be an element closer to the target element in the DOM hierarchy like a parent container but make sure that whatever element you use there is a static element in that it exists on pageload and is not removed at any point

**For the best performance:**

When your elements are static (they exist on page load and are not removed and re-added later **OR** they are added to the page before your binding function is called) you should target them as specifically as possible like

```
$('#some-element').click(function(){
});
```

When your elements are dynamic (added after page load or removed and added back later like your case here) you should target the closest static parent of the target like

```
$('#closest-static-parent').on('click', '#some-element', function(){
});
```

If you're not sure what the closest static parent will be, the below will alway work but you shouldn't use this all the time as the performance is not as good:

```
$(document).on('click', '#some-element', function(){
});
```

The idea with `.on()` is that you are binding the function to an element that will always exist on the page and the binding listens for clicks on **descendants of the bound element**. When it "hears" a click on a descendant, it checks if the descendant matches the selector provided (in this case `#some-element`) and if it does, the function is called.

The further away the bound element is from the target element in the DOM, the more checks take place and your function becomes less performant. The closer bound element is to the target element in the DOM, fewer checks take place and your function becomes more performant.

If you bind to `document`, anytime you click anywhere on the page, the function will check if the clicked element has the provided selector (thats going to be a lot of checks).

But, if you bind to the target's static parent element, the check will only be performed if you click on a child of the bound element.

**For completeness**

You could also, re-bind the function after you add the new element to the page like:

```
$('#some-element').bind('click', function(event) { // function bound to existing element
    alert('works');
});
$('#some-element').remove(); // remove the element 
$('#some-parent').append('<div id="some-element">'); // add the element back (will no longer have the function bound to it)

$('#some-element').bind('click', function(event) { // re-bind the function
    alert('working again');
});
```

But the previous approach is a much better one.

Comment: It looks like a newbie problem, but here I am, a newbie. It solved the problem! Maybe you can tell me if it's a good practice to bind all the functions to `document`. If I don't understand wrong, the biggest problem would be to remove the whole document in the DOM (if this is theoretically possible, which I don't really know)

Comment: Thanks for the fabulous explanation!